# specify typescript for generic function like Math

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code in TS

```
const arr = ["123.2", "abc", "78.3"];
console.log(arr.map((v) => (!isNaN(v) ? Math.floor(v) : v)));
```

but it gave warning because "abc" is string and isNaN and Math expect number, in this case what should I do? I know doing `(v:any)` will solve the issue but I'm looking for better solution.

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-burnell-j3nyc?file=/src/index.ts:205-306

Comment: What about converting it to a number first? `isNaN(Number('abc'))` -- I know it works currently, but maybe typescript needs it converted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+` before each element to convert to numbers and then perform a check:

```
const arr = ["123.2", "abc", "78"];
console.log(arr.map(el => isNaN(+el) ? el : +el))
```